# Calling getter in windows form from cpp class c++ returns nothing

Tags: forms, c++-cli, clr, getter

I have a cpp class and a windows form. In cpp class I have declared getters(`return char`) and setters. The thing is that when I call the getters in form they seem to return nothing. I test the cpp in console project and it works fine. Here is a snippet of my code in Form.h:

```
vector<NewProduct> products = getPhotosFromDB();

char* photoChar = products[0].getName();
String^ result;
result = marshal_as<String^>( photoChar );
label2->Text = String::Format(L"name= {0} ",  result);
```

** The connection works fine and the size of the vector is the right one. But When i run the project I got `"name=" (blank )`
or sometimes `"name=[]" (a square).`

Answer (score 0):

The square makes me think of an encoding problem, like if `getName()` doesn't actually return an array of 8-bit characters, but maybe an array of wide characters. You should use a debugger to check the memory at the location pointed by `photoChar`.

**Edit:** Also, check the width of your label. It's possible that it's too short to display the text, and is not automatically resized.